# Python Social Auth. User login creating new user instead of using existing one

Tags: python, django, python-social-auth

I suspect the reason of the error but I don't know how to solve it, this is what happened:

I did a `pg_dump` on a local database and then a `pg_restore` on the production database on Heroku. Now, when someone with a already existing username tries to login (using facebook or google etc), PSA creates a new user with a random number appended at the end instead of login the existing user in.

For example, the user with the username **JohnSmith** logs in with FB, because **JohnSmith** already exists in the db, it creates a new user with the username **JohnSmit654f6b654**

I guess the `pg_restore` I used to restore the database backup somehow didn't include some important psa tables. I'd like to know which Python Social Auth tables I should restore manually so that it works correctly. Or... maybe there is a different reason for the error. Thanks for your help.

Btw, Im using Django 1.8 on Heroku.

**Edit**

My Social Auth Pipeline:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_details',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_uid',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.auth_allowed',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.social_user',
    'social.pipeline.user.get_username',
    'social.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.associate_user',
    'social.pipeline.social_auth.load_extra_data',
    'social.pipeline.user.user_details',
    'letrasclub.utils.create_profile'
)
```

Its the normal pipeline + `create_profile`, that last pipeline only creates a profile for the user if it doesn't have one. It probably isn't the source of the problem cause the problem is the pipeline is creating new users, that happens in `'social.pipeline.user.create_user'`.

Comment: What does your `SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE` setting contain?

Comment: @Brandon, Thnx for the answer. Added the pipeline to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, Nikolay F answer helped me but it is not the answer to this question.

This is what solved it for me, just in case someone finds it useful:

Do a `manage.py dumpdata` on the old database (which has the correct data on the social auth tables, including `social_auth_usersocialauth`)

```
 python manage.py dumpdata default > social.json
```

The trick here is to know that Python Social Auth's doesn't have an app label but the command works with `default`.

Then, pushed the file to heroku and ran:

```
heroku run python manage.py loaddata social.json
```

That solved it.

Comment: `python manage.py dumpdata social_auth > baza_social.json`, flushing the table and then importing it, worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Check **social_auth_usersocialauth** table. It contains link between social network user id and django user id.

Comment: And they're displayed in the `PYTHON SOCIAL AUTH` of the `/admin` module. Thanks!